# Echoing Javascript not alerting

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'] ;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if (invalidChars($username, $password) > 0){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                , 'alert(fejl);'
                        , '</script>';

    }
}


function invalidChars($user, $password){
    $invalidPattern = "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/";

    return preg_match($invalidPattern, $user) + preg_match($invalidPattern, $password);
}
?>
```

However when then function invalidChars > 0 no alert is displayed.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? im rather new to web development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass string fejl in double quotes

```
if (invalidChars($username, $password) > 0){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' , 'alert("fejl");' , '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The objet `fejl` you passed in to alert does not exist.  This should be causing a javascript error.  I think you want to pass in the object `"fejl"` which is a string that alert will render.

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around the string to be alerted: `alert("fejl")`, otherwise it's just a syntax error. Press F12 in your browser and open the error console to easily spot problems like this.